# duvida com somatorio Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho as seguintes tabelas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a tabela contamov, pode ter varias baixas do mesmo registro da tabela crecpa.
preciso Selecionar registros da tabela crecpa e o somatorio das baixas (campo valor) de cada registro, tentei com um subselect, mas sem sucesso, qual o jeito correto de fazer?

tentei dessa forma

```
SELECT con.id_crecpa,
    con.id_crecpa,
    con.descricao,
    con.diabase,
    con.dt_emissao,
    con.dt_quitacao,
    con.dt_vencto,
    con.id_plano_conta,
    con.nrparcela,
    con.obs,
    con.parcpai,
    con.qtdeparcela,
    con.saldo,
    con.status,
       con.tipo,
       REPLACE(con.valor, ',','.') AS valor,
       con.vencido,
       con.vlr_pago,
       pes.razao,
      pes.id_pessoa,
      pla.descricao,
      (SELECT SUM(a.valor) FROM contamov a INNER JOIN crecpa b ON b.id_crecpa = a.id_crecpa GROUP BY a.valor ) AS ddd,
       CASE 
       WHEN (con.dt_vencto) < CURDATE() THEN 'sim'
       WHEN (con.dt_vencto) > CURDATE() THEN 'nao'
       WHEN (con.dt_vencto) = CURDATE() THEN 'hoje'    
  END AS venc       
FROM crecpa con
INNER JOIN pessoa pes ON con.id_pessoa = pes.id_pessoa
INNER JOIN plano_conta pla ON con.id_plano_conta = pla.id_plano_conta   
WHERE con.id_empresa = 6
AND con.tipo = "Credito"
AND con.status = "Ativo"
AND con.dt_vencto BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2019/05/10'
ORDER BY con.dt_vencto ASC
```

Comment: Essa querie deveria ter um subquerie para se resolver mais correlacionada a querie principal. Vou postar um exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta é meio confusa, mas se entendi bem deseja somar todos os registros contidos na tabela **contamov** correlacionando com o id primário da tabela **crecpa**.
No caso acredito que bastaria a subquerie abaixo para somar todos os valores contidos no atributo valor filtrando por cada id_crecpa que está sendo obtido da querie principal.

```
  SELECT ...  (SELECT SUM(valor) FROM contamov WHERE id_crecpa = 
  con.id_crecpa) 
  As valor FROM crecpa con WHERE con.id_empresa = 6 ....
```

O detalhe é  que essa é uma subquerie correlacionada, porque utilizamos o alias da tabela no caso **con** para referenciar a **querie principal** e filtrar os dados dentro de nossa subquerie.

Relamente não fiz testes na querie mas o conceito é esse abaixo:

```
SELECT con.id_crecpa,
       con.id_crecpa,
       con.descricao,
       con.diabase,
       con.dt_emissao,
       con.dt_quitacao,
       con.dt_vencto,
       con.id_plano_conta,
       con.nrparcela,
       con.obs,
       con.parcpai,
       con.qtdeparcela,
       con.saldo,
       con.status,
       con.tipo,
       REPLACE(con.valor, ',','.') AS valor,
       con.vencido,
       con.vlr_pago,
       pes.razao,
       pes.id_pessoa,
       pla.descricao,
       (SELECT SUM(valor) FROM contamov WHERE id_crecpa = con.id_crecpa) 
       As valor,
       CASE 
           WHEN (con.dt_vencto) < CURDATE() THEN 'sim'
           WHEN (con.dt_vencto) > CURDATE() THEN 'nao'
           WHEN (con.dt_vencto) = CURDATE() THEN 'hoje'    
      END AS venc       
FROM crecpa con
INNER JOIN pessoa pes ON con.id_pessoa = pes.id_pessoa
INNER JOIN plano_conta pla ON con.id_plano_conta = pla.id_plano_conta   
WHERE con.id_empresa = 6
AND con.tipo = "Credito"
AND con.status = "Ativo"
AND con.dt_vencto BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2019/05/10'
ORDER BY con.dt_vencto ASC
```